# How to return a tuple array recursively in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I have the following function:

```
function :: [String] -> [[Int]] -> ([[Int]],[[Int]])
```

I would like to know if it is possible to do something like this:

```
function :: [String] -> [[Int]] -> ([[Int]],[[Int]])
function a (b:bs) = if condition then ([[]], [b]) ++ function a bs else 
([b], [[]]) ++ function a bs
```

Of course I could write two functions which returns each [[Int]] but I would like to do it in a more  appropriate way for Haskell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `map`?

```
import Data.Monoid
f :: t -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
f a = mconcat . map part
  where part b = if True then ([], [b]) else ([b], [])
```

So we let `part` choose which list our element of `b` will go in and let `` `map ``, and `mconcat` to flatten it.

It's idiomatic haskell to avoid explicit recursion so while you can fix your code by substituting `mappend` for `++` since you asked for the more appropriate haskell way I'll suggest this.

Oh also, you could just use `break`

```
f s = break $ \b -> condition
```

Comment: This works good for me. There is only one mistake which I don't understand. My output contains many []. I thought that [] will not be added to the final output.

Comment: So with ([], b) I actually mean, that the first or the second value is empty.

Comment: @user2925688 Should be fixed now

Comment: I probably would need the base case `f [] _`! how would I add this in that case?

Comment: @user2925688 You don't need a base case, there's no recursion

Comment: Yes, but it could be, that I get an input like this:
`function [] [[1,3,4],[1,3,2]]` and so my output should look like this:
`([],[])`

Answer (score 5):

There is a monoid instance for a tuple:

```
(Monoid a, Monoid b) => Monoid (a, b)
```

So the result of mappend will be:

```
([1], [2]) `mappend` ([3], [4])
([1, 3], [2, 4])
```

So basically you just replace ++ with mappend in your example

Comment: Preferrably write just `([1], [2]) <> ([3], [4])`.

Comment: Note that the mappend for tuples isn't lazy, so this might be a bad idea for the current use case with long lists.

Answer (score 2):

The most Haskellic(?) way would probably be to use `unzip`:

```
function a bs = unzip $ function' a bs
    where function' a (b:bs) = (if condition then ([], b) else (b, [])) : function' a bs
          function' _ [] = []  -- You forgot the base case.
```